# Does it matter if I present in a PhD interview a topic which is partially unrelated to the PhD one?

Tags: phd, thesis, presentation, interview, chemistry

I have a PhD interview coming up on organic chemistry in a few days. As part of the interview process I have to give a short presentation regarding a research which I am currently undertaking. However the current research is more related towards bio-organic (more biology). Does this matter if I still present a topic which isn't exactly in the organic field?

I should however stress that I am a chemist and done a lot of organic research for my undergraduate but for my masters I took a different turn but now wish to return to the organic side.

Comment: Better, write to them in mail your situation. They must have already judged from your submitted profile about your present works. Is not it?

Comment: They do know based on the CV and cover letter I submitted, however I am worried this aspect would greatly affect the way they see me as a potential candidate.

Comment: If you keep thinking about how would they see you, you can never do good in your presentation. So, just prepare your presentation  based on your present work, and keep stressing that you would do the organic work. Probably, you could emphasize on any work that you had done earlier.

Comment: I wouldn't keep stressing it. Just introduce your talk by explaining that you changed fields for your masters but intend to return to organic chemistry. Then concentrate on explaining your current research as clearly as possible.

Comment: Alright, I will contact them just in case but thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

I was offered a job in a sub-discipline that I was not a specialist in.  Everyone knew this; I was quite truthful about the situation.  If this should happen, think carefully because much **extra** work will be expected on **your** part.  I take it as obvious that *you* should be and have been honest throughout all this.  However, you still must evaluate very carefully what to do if the job-offer is too far removed from your field-of-study.  From:  One who has been there.